# D std.regex - return as text

Tags: regex, d

Is there a possibility to return text which was used to create regular expression?

Something like this:

```
auto r = regex(r"[0-9]", "g"); // create regular expression
writeln(r.dumpAsText());       // this would write: [0-9]
```

There is nothing in http://dlang.org/phobos/std_regex.html on this. (or at least I did not notice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because it compiles the regex, and I don't believe it even stores the string after compilation.

The best thing to do is just to store the string yourself on creation.

[Source for `struct Regex`](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/regex.d#L1956)

As you can see, it doesn't store the pattern string, only the bytecode.

Comment: Looked at the source.  It's somewhat complicated but I believe you are correct about it not retaining the pattern string.

Answer (score 1):

Typically using a subtype would work, but unfortunately ti doesn't due to failed template constraints. E.g. a plausible solution (that doesn't work right now) would be to wrap the regex as a subtype:

```
auto myregex(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    struct RegexWrap
    {
        Regex!char reg;
        alias reg this;
        string dumpAsText;
    }

    return RegexWrap(regex(arg1, arg2), arg1);
}

void main()
{
    auto r = myregex(r"[0-9]", "g"); // create regular expression
    writeln(r.dumpAsText);       // this would write: [0-9]   
    writeln(match("12345", r));  // won't work 
}
```

The `match` function in std.regex won't work with this wrapper struct even when using a subtype, because it fails this template constraint:

```
public auto match(R, RegEx)(R input, RegEx re)
    is(RegEx == Regex!(BasicElementOf!R)
```

Even if you changed the header to this, it still won't work:

```
public auto match(R)(R input, Regex!(BasicElementOf!R) re)
```

The only way it would work is if the type was explicit so the subtype could be passed:

```
public auto match(R)(R input, Regex!char re)
```

I find this to be an awkward part of D that could be improved.